# Back button broken after refresh using history-based Ember.Location

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use the 'history' router implementation instead of the default 'hash', and have enabled logging of transitions:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

This works: clicking links between pages works fine, the back button works fine, all of the router transitions get logged in the console, etc.

But if I manually refresh the browser (Chrome 25), the back/forward buttons stop working. The URL in the address bar changes appropriately, but nothing in the page changes. No errors in the console, and no output from `LOG_TRANSITIONS`.

Refreshing + back/forward works perfectly fine using the default hash-based locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the way Ember works with pushState-based history. Already fixed, just not released yet:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2234